# QtUDPSocket: understanding ReadyRead() signal processing

Tags: c++, qt, sockets, udp

There is an [example](https://doc-snapshots.qt.io/qt5-5.4/qudpsocket.html#writeDatagram) from the official QT documentation of `QUdpSocket` datagrams reading:

```
void Server::initSocket()
{
    udpSocket = new QUdpSocket(this);
    udpSocket->bind(QHostAddress::LocalHost, 7755);

    connect(udpSocket, SIGNAL(readyRead()),
            this, SLOT(readPendingDatagrams()));
}

void Server::readPendingDatagrams()
{
    while (udpSocket->hasPendingDatagrams()) {
        QByteArray datagram;
        datagram.resize(udpSocket->pendingDatagramSize());
        QHostAddress sender;
        quint16 senderPort;

        udpSocket->readDatagram(datagram.data(), datagram.size(),
                                &sender, &senderPort);

        processTheDatagram(datagram);
    }
}
```

I'm trying to understand what exactly happens, when `readyRead()` signal emits. In the `while` loop (in `Server::readPendingDatagrams()` slot) we read available datagrams, but what happens if new datagram appends to the socket, while we still read the previous datagrams batch? `readyRead()` signal will be emited again? But how `while` loop will be read the data in this case - from last appended datagram or in some other way?

Comment: See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13773374/qudpsocket-cannot-receive-datagram): you **must** read **all** pending datagram for the signal to be triggered again. As for messages order, they are read in FIFO fashion. Clearly, since it is UDP, u can't relay on such order to ensure *content* ordering.