# Receiving Udp packets using Qt

Tags: qt, udp

I'm trying to receive udp packets which are send to the braodcast. According to wireshark they are incoming but I don't receive anything. At first Ithough the firewall was blocking me but even with the firewall turned down I receive nothing. I also need to say that I'm new to C++ so I have some problems understanding the syntax of examples in the qt documentation. I don't understand why it doesn't work, the answer from [Possible duplikate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13773374/qudpsocket-cannot-receive-datagram) totally crushed my code.

```css
#include "receiver.h"

Receiver::Receiver(QWidget *parent)
    : QWidget(parent)
{
    udpSocket = new QUdpSocket(this);
    udpSocket->bind(12375, QUdpSocket::ShareAddress);

    connect(udpSocket, SIGNAL(readyRead()),
            this, SLOT(processPendingDatagrams()));

}

void Receiver::processPendingDatagrams()
{
    QByteArray datagram;
    while (udpSocket->hasPendingDatagrams())
    {
        datagram.resize(int(udpSocket->pendingDatagramSize()));
        udpSocket->readDatagram(datagram.data(), datagram.size());
        statusLabel->setText(tr("Received datagram: \"%1\"")
                             .arg(datagram.constData()));
    }
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [QUdpSocket: Cannot receive datagram](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13773374/qudpsocket-cannot-receive-datagram)

Comment: Nop, I already looked at it, the answer there do not help at all for me.

Comment: Not sure if [this helps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13666789/receiving-udp-broadcast-packets-on-linux).